# Share or sync user table data with another user table

Tags: plugins, users, mysql, table, sync

I have a software and a wordpress installed in the same database, there is a wordpress "user" table and the software "user_soft" table. Is there any way or plugin to sync the two tables so that when the user register in wordpress, automatically register in "user_soft"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to WPSE. Asking for plugin recommendations is considered [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, so here's an action approach to the problem.

[`wp_insert_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/) takes care of adding new users to the database. The last action the function fires is [`user_register`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/), which *"Fires immediately after a new user is registered"*. You could hook your function to this action and use it to update the custom DB table.

In your action function you can use the global [`$wpdb`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) to manipulate your database tables whether they are standard WP tables or not. (You can also use `wpdb` class to connect to other databases, too.)

To insert new data into the database you can use the [`wpdb::insert( string $table, array $data, array|string $format = null )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/) method.

If there's some user data that needs to be kept updated and synced, then you can hook to [`profile_update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/) action, which `wp_insert_user()` also fires, but *"...immediately after an existing user is updated"*.